# Why can't i spawn a pre-defined closure in a crossbeam scope

Tags: multithreading, rust

Why does this worK:

```
extern crate crossbeam;
fn main(){
    let v: Vec<i32> = vec![1, 2, 3];

    crossbeam::scope(|s|{
        s.spawn(|_|{
            for e in v{
                println!("{}", e);
            }
        });
    }).unwrap();
}
```

when this does not:

```
extern crate crossbeam;
fn main(){
    let v: Vec<i32> = vec![1, 2, 3];
    let closure = |_|{
        for e in v{
            println!("{}", e);
        }
    };

    crossbeam::scope(|s|{
        s.spawn(closure);
    }).unwrap();
}
```

with the compiler giving me the error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:11:11
   |
11 |         s.spawn(closure);
   |           ^^^^^ one type is more general than the other
   |
   = note: expected type `std::ops::FnOnce<(&crossbeam::thread::Scope<'_>,)>`
              found type `std::ops::FnOnce<(&crossbeam::thread::Scope<'_>,)>`
```

Is it because of higher rank trait-bounds?

And if so how can i fix it while keeping the closure defined outside of the scope?

I am a newcomer to rust and i found the error confusing because the type it found is the type it expected as far as i can tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that rust cannot correctly infer the type of the closure (without going into detail let's say that the compiler is not soo good in type inference betwen closures).

In your case you just had to add a type anotation on all the closure arguments, for instance

```
extern crate crossbeam;
fn main(){
    let v: Vec<i32> = vec![1, 2, 3];
    let closure =  |sr:& crossbeam::thread::Scope<'_> /* anotate the closure arguments types */|{
        for e in v{
            println!("{}", e);
        }
    };

    crossbeam::scope(|s|{
        s.spawn(closure);
    }).unwrap();
}
```

Note your issue is similar to [this one](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/solved-one-type-is-more-general-than-the-other-but-they-are-exactly-the-same/25194/4).

Comment: Thanks, i guess i was pushing the compiler a bit trying to get it to infer for me.